Кастомный маркер "текущего положения пользователя" в Yandex Maps API V3
Вводные:

NextJS 14 приложение
Yandex Maps API V3 for react (@yandex/ymaps3-types)
Yandex Maps Controls package (@yandex/ymaps3-controls@0.0.1)

Задача:
Необходимо реализовать кастомный маркер для отображения текушего положения пользователя на карте. В идеале использовать полностью самостоятельную иконку, блок, стилизацию.
В настоящий момент используется модуль YMapGeolocaitonContol.
На первом изображении иконка по-умолчанию:

Любой другой вид иконки, к примеру:

Возможно ли вообще кастомизировать данный компонент?
Или такое поведение можно реализовать только самостоятельно?
Буду признателен за любую помощь. Спасибо.
<YMap
      margin={[20, 20, 20, 20]}
      location={location}
      ref={mapRef}
      copyrightsPosition="bottom left"
      zoomRange={{
        min: 4,
        max: 18,
      }}
    >
      <YMapDefaultSchemeLayer />

      <YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer />

      {renderedMapPins}

      <YMapControls position="right bottom" orientation="vertical">
        {/* Add the geolocation control to the map */}
        {YMapGeolocationControl && <YMapGeolocationControl />}
        {/* Add the first zoom control to the map */}
        {YMapZoomControl && <YMapZoomControl />}
      </YMapControls>
    </YMap>


Настроек для кастомизации у YMapGeolocaitonContol нет. Вы можете собрать собственный аналог по примеру из ymaps3.geolocation.getPosition().
